# Can I make a div class clickable?

Tags: css, html, button, href

I've tried adding a `href` into the `cart-button` class like the HTML code below:

```
    <div class="cart-button" href="#shopping-cart" alt="view-shopping-cart"><span>Shopping Cart (0)</span>
      <div class="cart-dropdown">
        <p class="emptycart">Your shopping cart is empty.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see i inserted `href` into the `cart-button` class, however when i click the button the page doesn't go forward to the `href` page.

is it possible to make a `href` into a `div` like above, or would this be wrong?

Here is the CSS for the HTML code above:

```
    .cart-button {
      position: relative;
      left: 700px;
      bottom: 57px;
      width: 180px;
      height:30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: url("images/cart-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }

    .cart-button:hover { background: url("images/cart-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -30px; }

    .cart-button span {
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #373737;
      padding: 9px 10px 10px 53px;
    }

    .cart-button span:hover { color: #000; }

    .cart-dropdown {
      position: relative;
      top: 30px;
      right: 71px;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .cart-button:hover .cart-dropdown {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .emptycart {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 11px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 8px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
      color: #fff;
      background: #202020;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an `<a>` tag. You can't add `href` attributes to arbitrary elements to make them clickable. It's not the `href` that makes `<a>` tags clickable, is the fact that it's an `<a>` tag.

You could achieve something similar with JavaScript, but you shouldn't. Use a tag that semantically represents a clickable element - `<a>` or `<button>`.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know, made it much clearer for me. Still learning HTML and CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in/"><div class="cart-button"  alt="view-shopping-cart"></div></a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4EwU9/)

Answer (score 1):

In html5 you can wrap block elements in `<a>` tags.

http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

So...

```
<a href="#"><div>...</div></a>
```

Comment: I love that you mention this, because previously it was invalid. However meagar's answer is more complete - I would love if these were in the same answer ;)

Comment: Haha, yeah shame. It still doesn't feel right though does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that without using an anchor tag.

You could however add an onClick event to the div to trigger whatever event you want. However, I would personally prefer the former.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can also go with JQuery so your code will look something similar like this:

```
$(function () {
     $('.cart-button').click(function() {
          //GO SOMEWHERE or DO SOMETHING HERE
     });
});
```

Don't forget to link JQuery library in your page.

Happy Coding...